# RavenDB Java client missing StringUtils

Tags: java, ravendb

I downloaded the RavenDB Java client 3.2.1 jar from [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/ravendb/ravendb-client/3.2.1/ravendb-client-3.2.1.jar), created a new Java project in Ecplise, added the jar to the list of references, then took these three lines

```
IDocumentStore store = new DocumentStore(ravenDbUrl, "todo-db");
store.initialize();
store.executeIndex(new TodoByTitleIndex());
```

from [here](https://ayende.com/blog/168354/what-is-new-in-ravendb-3-0-jvm-client-api), replaced the values with my db-specific names, and expected some sign of life from the db. Instead, I'm getting "`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils`". 
I must admit, it's been a while since I've done Java, but surely this isn't missing something glaringly obvious, is it ?!
I have included the commons-lang3-3.5.jar file as well, but it's not taking that. Could you please point me in the right direction ?

Thanks !

Comment: These: http://i.imgur.com/SmjxBNr.png are all the dependencies requred by RavenDB Java client 3.2.1. Quite a few. You should use Maven (or a similar dependency manager) and let it handle it for you, otherwise you'll go crazy.

Comment: Slanec, thanks. I was hoping it would be a quick exercise, but it seems I need to go back and acquaint myself with Maven. Or, rather - the Maven and Ecplise duet.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the "official" pom to my Eclipse project made it compile and run. 
For the record, here's the pom, in case someone needs a base from which to investigate:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>net.ravendb</groupId>
    <artifactId>ravendb-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>ravendb-client</artifactId>
  <name>RavenDB Java Client</name>

  <properties>
    <queryDsl.version>3.1.1</queryDsl.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
      <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
      <version>${queryDsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.undercouch</groupId>
      <artifactId>bson4jackson</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test deps -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
      <artifactId>querydsl-collections</artifactId>
      <version>${queryDsl.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
      <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>querydsl-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-process</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>target/generated-test-sources/java</outputDirectory>
              <processor>net.ravendb.querydsl.RavenDBAnnotationProcessor</processor>
              <options>
                <querydsl.entityAccessors>true</querydsl.entityAccessors>
              </options>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Source-Hash>${sourceHash}</Source-Hash>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <!-- version 2.2 has bug: https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/issues/51 -->
        <version>2.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>

    <profile>
      <id>pack</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/dist.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
              <attach>false</attach>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>coverage</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.2.201302030002</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>jacoco-site</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```